# OrientDB - expand() with additional fields

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

Starting from the following query:

```
MATCH 
    {class: MYCLASS}-->{as: a}-->{as: b} 
RETURN 
    $matches
```

which returns:

```
PROPERTIES
=============
a     | b
-------------
#25:0 | #10:0
#25:0 | #9:0
#29:0 | #11:0
#29:0 | #33:0
```

I want all the fields from `b` and the class of `a` returned. Also I don't know what fields are in `b`.
Basically this:

```
SELECT
    expand(b), a.@class
FROM
    (MATCH 
        {class: MYCLASS}-->{as: a}-->{as: b} 
    RETURN 
        $matches)
;
```

which of course returns the error message: `Cannot execute a query with expand() together with other projections DB name="test"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select $a as b, $b.a_class as class
let $a = (select expand(b) from (MATCH {class: MYCLASS}-->{as: a}-->{as: b} RETURN $matches)),
$b = (select a.@class as a_class from (MATCH {class: MYCLASS}-->{as: a}-->{as: b} RETURN $matches))    
unwind class
```

This is what you get:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: unfortunately your solution doesn't return the desired result, since (in the table view) it returns in every row an array of of every `b`with an Array of every class of `a`. but the relationship between class of `a` and `b` is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

@Michela Bonizzi though your answer didn't gave me the exact result I wanted it gave me a new idea

```
SELECT 
    *, in().@class as a_class
FROM
    (MATCH 
        {class: BEWERTUNG}-->{as: a}-->{as: b} 
    RETURN 
        expand(b))
UNWIND a_class
```

[queryresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Rik.png)